# Change cell value dynamically in MUI Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

In my Data Grid I have 9 columns where you can see there are two columns named `Rate` and `Transfer`. I also have a column named `Total` where I want to show the multiplication result of `Rate` and `Transfer` with the change of `Transfer` cell's value. **Note that** I've made `Transfer` column editable so that the value of `Total` column changes with Transfer value. In `DataGrid` there is a prop called `onCellFocusOut()` which gives you the cell value after you click outside the cell. But this doesn't give you the updated value. I tried using `useEffect()` and `useState()` to set the value of the `Transfer` cell and update the `Total` accordingly. But it didn't work. Hopefully I've explained clearly about what I want to achieve here.

**My code**

```
const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
  return <Slide direction="left" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

function FullScreenDialog({ open, handleClose }) {
  const columns = [
    {
      field: "Lot",
      headerName: "Lot#",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
    { field: "Bill", headerName: "Bill#", width: 130, editable: false },
    {
      field: "Shelf",
      headerName: "Shelf",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
    {
      field: "Bin",
      headerName: "Bin",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
    {
      field: "Rate",
      headerName: "Rate",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
    {
      field: "Stock",
      headerName: "Stock Balance Qty.",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
    {
      field: "Transfer",
      headerName: "Transfer Qty.",
      width: 200,
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: "Total",
      headerName: "Total",
      width: 200,
      editable: false,
    },
  ];

  // React.useEffect(() => {
  //   setTotal(rate * transfer);
  //   console.log("total", total);
  // }, [transfer]);

  const [transferCellValue, setTransferCellValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(1);
  console.log("transfer cell value", transferCellValue);
  const defaultRows = [
    {
      id: 1,
      Lot: "2101000134",
      Bill: "M0000013092",
      Shelf: "W13-A1",
      Bin: "B01",
      Rate: 221,
      Stock: 128.0,
      Transfer: 12,
      Total: total,
    },
  ];

  // console.log(transferCellValue);

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        fullScreen
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
      >
        <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
          <DataGrid
            rows={defaultRows}
            columns={columns}
            onCellFocusOut={(e) => console.log(e.value)}
          />
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want is that the total column to be calculated by `Transfer * Rate`, you can use [`valueGetter`](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/grid-col-def/#:%7E:text=rendering%20its%20value.-,valueGetter,-%3F) to return a dynamic value.

> valueGetter: Function that allows to get a specific data instead of field to render in the cell.

```
{
  field: "Total",
  headerName: "Total",
  width: 200,
  valueGetter: (params) => params.row.Transfer * params.row.Rate
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datagrid-dynamic-column-tdod5

Comment: Thanks, but what if later I have to add another row at the bottom which shows total of all the total values from all rows?

Comment: Where would you like to present the total of totals? in a row, in the header / footer, outside the DataGrid?

Comment: in a separate row, outside the data grid

Comment: Should be using `valueFormatter`